# To caress me from the front, you first need to lick me from behind. What am I?

Tags: riddle

This is my English translation of a famous puzzle that is apparently little known in the West.

Comment: This is a nice riddle, but it may be a bit dated: in many countries the answer is no longer valid, because our behinds are always sticky, if you know what I mean :-)

Comment: ‘Caress’ doesn't seem to fit the answer very well, either.

Comment: Do I need to create a #metoo tag for puzz now? :P

Comment: rot13(cuvyngryl) even sounds like it should be a kinkier hobby than it actually is

Comment: I thought of the accepted answer, but dismissed it due to the phrasing, "you first need to" which implies that you are prevented from touching the front until..  I'd prefer "before you caress me from the front, you should lick me from behind" or even "Caressing me from the front is pointless until you've licked me from behind" but that doesn't quite fit the double entendre as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Maybe you are

> a stamp.
>
>  You first lick it to make it sticky, and then "caress" it when you
>  press it to the envelope.

Comment: Wow, great :) This is the correct answer.

Comment: Does anyone still lick $*&^%$? That's so last century!

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, I've seen people do it even when it's not necessary. lol

Answer (score 15):

An answer's already been accepted, but since the riddle isn't very specific I think there may be other correct answers. One answer I came up with is

> a page in a novel

Explanation if you need it:

> Many people turn pages by licking their finger and then turning the page. This requires a bit of a liberal view of "to lick", but maybe it makes more sense in another language.

Or, even better,

> The sticky part of an envelope

This is the same logic as the accepted answer:

> Which, of course, is licked, then "caressed" to seal the letter. I imagine many similar adhesive-related answers exist.

Comment: I was going to suggest rot13(ebyyvat cncre), but didn't realize they have an adhesive, since I don't use them.

Answer (score 6):

ice cream cone wrapped with paper

Comment: I don't even want to know... :-)

Comment: I'm just going to say: that's unsanitary. I would assume that glue is applied wet, so there is no "licking" necessary.